# Setting variable with Grand Central Dispatch not retrievable

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa

I'm trying to set and a NSURL using grand central dispatch, however it appears that the variable is set and accessible until you try to access it outside of the grand central dispatch block.

```
-(void)viewDidLoad {

[super viewDidLoad];

dispatch_queue_t backgroundQueue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0);
dispatch_async(backgroundQueue,^{

    self.ubiquitousURL = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLForUbiquityContainerIdentifier:nil];

   NSLog(@"ubiq inside: %@", self.ubiquitousURL);

    if (self.ubiquitousURL) {

        self.iCloudDocURL = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@Documents", self.ubiquitousURL]];
        self.iCloudDocString = [self.iCloudDocURL absoluteString];

        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(loadFiles) name: UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification object:nil];

    } else {

        /* change to the main queue if you want to do something with the UI. For example: */
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),^{

            UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Please enable iCloud" message:nil delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];

            [alert show];

        });

    }

});


NSLog(@"ubiq outside: %@", self.ubiquitousURL);

}
```

The first `NSLog` which, starts with `ubiq inside` returns the correct URL, while `ubiq outside` returns NULL. I'm using ARC, so no need to mention memory or anything similar... this is a GCD problem.

Do you know why `self.ubiquitousURL` is not accessible outside of the GCD block? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`dispatch_async` means "run this later".  Thus, the code inside the block doesn't run immediately; it runs at some later time, after the "outside" `NSLog` call has already been run.  If you were to, for instance, put `sleep(5)` before the `NSLog` call, you would probably see the value.  (You shouldn't really do that in the actual code, though; it would basically freeze the app for five seconds.)

If you want to run more code on the main queue after you've set that property, do something like this:

```
dispatch_async(backgroundQueue,^{
    self.ubiquitousURL = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLForUbiquityContainerIdentifier:nil];

    NSLog(@"ubiq inside: %@", self.ubiquitousURL);

    if (self.ubiquitousURL) {
        self.iCloudDocURL = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@Documents", self.ubiquitousURL]];
        self.iCloudDocString = [self.iCloudDocURL absoluteString];

        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(loadFiles) name: UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification object:nil];

        // ************** NEW HOTNESS HERE **************
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),^{
            NSLog(@"ubiq outside: %@", self.ubiquitousURL);
        });
    } else {
        /* change to the main queue if you want to do something with the UI. For example: */
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),^{
            UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Please enable iCloud" message:nil delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
            [alert show];
        });
    }
});
```

Replace that `NSLog` line with a method call to do actual work if that's what you want to do once you've retrieved the iCloud URL.

Comment: This looks great, thanks! Since there is a delay with `dispatch_async`, should I use `dispatch_sync` instead? Are there any issues that could occur with that?

Comment: `dispatch_sync` will pause the main queue of your app until the block completes, which in this case means until iCloud responds to your request.  A user with a bad connection (say, an AT&T user in New York) could experience a delay of several minutes.  The user will believe the app is "frozen", and if this code is run when your app launches, iOS may kill it off because it launched too slowly. In other words, I strongly recommend against using `dispatch_sync` here. Do whatever you want to do in the inner `dispatch_async` call.

Comment: “`dispatch_async` means "run this later". Thus, the code inside the block doesn't run immediately…” Moreover, even if the block *is* dispatched immediately, it may not get to the point where it assigns to the `ubiquitousURL` property before the code in the method tries to retrieve it. This is a straightforward race condition.

Answer (score 4):

You are making async call.  So this line `NSLog(@"ubiq outside: %@", self.ubiquitousURL);` will get executed whether or not your code inside backgroundQueue is done.

You would see the outside log first then inside log.